# Where's the version key into the gac?

Tags: .net, windows, gac

I'm installing 3rd party apps on our hosting platform. Version 11 works fine, loading a DLL from C:\Windows\assembly\gac\10.0.0.141 but after installing version 12, it looks instead in C:\Windows\assembly\gac\10.0.0.142 and fails and loads it from a common directory before deciding to hang itself. Oddly, v12 does the same but then seems to work.

My problem is I cannot find any file, registry entry, anything that has this 10.0.0.142 instead of 10.0.0.141, so I'm asking where [else] can I look?

Comment: Hard to decode, you are comparing "version 12" that doesn't work and "v12" that does work.  The paths you quoted are not real paths in the GAC.  The "gac" subdirectory only stores .NET 1.1 assemblies.  It doesn't have a subdirectory in it that has a version number as a name.  Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Closing this w/o resolution. We side-stepped the issue by brute force experimentation of shunting dlls into version-specific directories, quite why that helped is a mystery. FWIW, "version 12" and "v12" referred to the same thing, and btw real path was C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Sage.Common\10.0.0.142__6e1ad03deaa1eb79 and it looked in gac, then gac_32, then gac_msil, then gac again, before looking in the first directory in the path. Anyway, thanks for suggesting fuslogvw, I had never heard of that.